# Monogame - How do I make my if statement loop?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

The title of this question may sound stupid, but please read the entire question first, and yes, I'm aware of **all** types of loops and I'm able to use the perfectly fine when programming.

I'm building a 2D game, and when my `player` collides with a spike, I want another character to slowly walk (It's quite hard to explain, however that doesn't matter), but here's the code for it:

```
 if (player.Bounds.Intersects(anneTrigger.Bounds))
 {
      Anne.UpdateForAnne(gameTime);  
      Anne.LoadHumanContent(Content);
 }
```

Briefly explaining the code, the condition checks if the `player` has collided with the `anneTrigger` spike, then it calls `Anne.UpdateForAnne(gameTime)` and `Anne.LoadHumanContent(Content)`, which animates the character and makes the character walk, which is what I want, and works **perfectly fine**.

**What's the issue?**

The problem is, this only works whilst the `player` is on the spike, once my `player` walks past and off the spike, the other character stops walking, which is **not** what I want. I need it to continue as long as the player has collided with the spike already.

I have tried to use a loop instead of an if statement, but that just crashes my game. I'm sure I may have to use a boolean however I'm not too sure how, I have tried previously however it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a bool variable in the class outside of your update method.

```
private bool AnneActivated = false;

if (player.Bounds.Intersects(anneTrigger.Bounds))
{
   AnneActivated = true;
}

if(AnneActivated)
{
   Anne.UpdateForAnne(gameTime);  
   Anne.LoadHumanContent(Content);
}
```

Comment: The simplest solution is often the best. If you ever find yourself tracking too many bools I suggest reading about [state machines here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).

Comment: Just a quick aside, if you want to avoid wasting cycles check for the bool first, ie: if (!AnneActivated && InterSectMethod()) {do stuff}. This way if anne is already activated your engine won't keep checking for that collision (unless the gameplay requires it at that point still!).